# Using java.io.package / How to read data from a variable and store it in a file?

Tags: java, java-io

could someone please provide a hint how i can go about reading data from a variable (some string file) which holds my random computations and store the output in a text file and probably some functionality for working with it.

thanks,
steliyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 examples for you; the first is reading from a text file, the second is writing to one.

```
import java.io.*;
class FileRead {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("textfile.txt"));
            String strLine;
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
               // Print the content on the console
               System.out.println (strLine);
            }
            //Close the input stream
            br.close();
         } catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
             System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
         }
     }
 }


import java.io.*;
class FileWrite {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String var = "var";
        try {
            // Create file 
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(var);
            //Close the output stream
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i did that, but not able to find my file.txt  I searched the program directory, yet no file with this name, nothing.

Comment: @StelyianStoyanov That is probably because the relative path is putting the file somewhere unexpected. Try and use an absolute path like "C:\\test.txt" so you can find/confirm it.

Comment: Riyad Kalla, thank you for your response, but I am using a unix machine, how do i go about saving the file in this case ? Thanks!

Comment: something like /home/rama/scripts/text.txt

Comment: Many thanks! Worked fine, are there any actions i can perform on the file (within java)

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text. Unfortunately examples like this get copied again and again so can you can remove it from your example. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: I changed it; it could even be better by using finally to close the streams, but they are just examples to show how you can read and write from a file.